# How can I add an undo option at the end the code in PowerPoint using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I need to add a undo command after I save a copy of ppt, the below code works fine and has been written in excel VBA (note that `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Undo"`  did not work here):

```
Sub desired_slides_to_ppt()
    Dim ppApp, PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
    Dim FileNameString As String
    
    Dim target() As Variant
    Dim non_target() As Variant
    
    target = Application.Transpose(Range("W3:W13"))
    non_target = Application.Transpose(Range("Y3:Y106"))
    FileNameString = Range("file_name")
        
    Set ppApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    ppApp.Visible = msoTrue

    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations("WC Combined Maps v1.pptx")   
    
    ppPres.Slides.Range(non_target()).Delete
    ppPres.SaveCopyAs FileNameString, ppSaveAsDefault, msoTrue
    <<need undo command on ppPres>>
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think actions taken by VBA are undo-able, only those performed by the user via the user interface can be undone.  You'd need to write code to reverse the steps.  EDIT - maybe possible in PPT - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602332/powerpoint-vba-undo

Comment: VBA actions are undo-able ... I do this all the time when testing code. Run the VBA, check the results, notice a problem, hit Ctrl+Z, go back and correct the problem.  But that's *only* when I'm running the code in VBA. It appears that, like Vegas, what happens in Excel STAYS in Excel.  Parvez, it would probably be better to save a copy of your presentation, perform any necessary actions on that, save it, close it. If you kept the original open during all this, you're back where you started; otherwise, re-open the original file.

Answer (score 1):

Use your reference to the Powerpoint application, `ppApp`:

```
ppApp.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Undo"
```